Custom rom building fail on Poco X3 Pro
The Error
I tried with all custom roms, but is the same so can anyone help. In my case I'm using Poco X3 Pro and I'm experiencing this issue while trying to build the custom rom. I tried with all trees that are available for Poco X3 Pro from GitHub
product_source_root_dirs
